# Spring way to use custom annotation based factory pattern similar to LocalValidatorFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring

have annotation defined as

```
@Documented
@Target({ ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Transform {

    Class<? extends Transformer<?, ?>>[] transformBy();
}



public interface Transformer<A extends Annotation, T> {

        /**
         * <p>Implement the transform logic according to the way you want
         * 
         * @param value
         * @return
         */
        public Object doTransform(T value);
}
```

Now when ever, I want to use a transformer, then it can create annotation like

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Transform(transformBy=CommandRuleConstraintTransformer.class)
public @interface CommandStateTransformer {

    String message() default "Command Transformation.";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

and a implementation class defined in `transformed by` in the transform annotation will do the logic like below:

```
public class CommandRuleConstraintTransformer implements Transformer<CommandStateTransformer, Object>{
    @Override
    public Object doTransform(Object target) {
        try {
            // Fire rules
            commandStatelessKSession.execute(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{target}));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("[EXCEPTION]- Transforming command state {}",e.toString());
        }
        return target;
    }
}
```

My question is, How I will instruct spring, to scan and manage a factory bean and when ever required can easily call like this:

```
@Autowired 
private TransformerFactory transformerFactory;
transformerFactory.doTransform(someargs);
```

Similar way the `<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>` works.

Please help..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that (I am not sure the simplest) is that: you can add your own implementation of CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor to your Spring configuration. Just like that

```
@Bean
public CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor commonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new MyBeanPostProcessor();
}
```

and then override one of the available public methods like

```
public class MyBeanPostProcessor extends CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor {

@Override
public PropertyValues postProcessPropertyValues(PropertyValues pvs,
        PropertyDescriptor[] pds, Object bean, String beanName)
        throws BeansException {

    // TODO 
    return super.postProcessPropertyValues(pvs, pds, bean, beanName);
}
}
```

And then every time spring does its Autowiring magic your method will be called. Having the bean object and class you have access to the fields and them annotations so basically you can do whatever you want.